# How do I get JAX to use the GPU on my M1 Mac

Tags: arm, gpu, apple-m1, jax

I am trying to run jax on my M1 machine and would really like it to use my GPU. I haven't figured out how to do this.

I think I pretty much followed every step of [this link.](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/8074#issuecomment-1148012748) In particular, what I did was

1. Uninstall anaconda and remove every instance of it on my computer
2. Reinstall anaconda with the arm version in particular
3. Create a conda environment I called `serotonin-gpu`. I install everything into this conda env from now on.
4. install PyTorch nightly (to get M1 GPU support)
5. install MoltenVK for mac support
6. clone HEAD of `jax` repo
7. build+install a wheel of `jaxlib`
8. install `jax`
9. Install latest snapsot of `iree`
10. Modify `jax/jax/_src/iree.py` as in the above link to pass extra flags.

I then tried to run the following code in `serotonin-gpu`, but it appears not to have utilized the gpu.

[image]

I don't really even know how to debug from here.

Some thoughts

1. Could it matter that I originally authored the notebook shown above in a environment that was using regular jax (i.e. wo trying to make it use the M1 GPU)?
2. There are some additional commands in the link I was following that appeared to be more related to `dalle-playground`
   They advised using the following code

```
# if you want to try the known-good CPU-only mode, then remove these env vars
JAX_PLATFORMS=iree JAX_IREE_BACKEND=vulkan python app.py 8080
```

I don't know where I would even type this commands in though

3. Are there better/more general resources for getting `jax` to use the GPU on M1s? I haven't found any yet though.
4. Is there any way to contact someone either at Jax or Apple and beg them to make these two great tools more compatible?

Comment: I think `jax` only supports NVidea GPU's. https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- JAX is heavily dependent on Tensorflow framework. When building JAX from [source](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#building-from-source), it requires to build Tensorflow from sources as well. Not clear why Pytorch is relevant here except getting Dalle to work
- Core of JAX is XLA compiler which does not seem to support Apple M1 GPU hardware target, not clear if LLVM backend exists for Apple M1 GPU.

You can switch your code to use CPU only, example below:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

# Global flag to set a specific platform, must be used at startup.
jax.config.update('jax_platform_name', 'cpu')
```